# Worker class not getting triggered by the OneTimeWorkRequest

Tags: java, android, constraints, worker, android-workmanager

I have this OneTimeWorkRequest that don't trigger my SendFeedbackMessageWorker.
The work request should get triggered with the constraint ".setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)", but whenever I try to send a message without network connected and then connect again, the class is never triggered.

Can anybody point out where this is broken?

```
private void handleFeedbackMessageFailure(Context context, FeedbackMessage message) {

        Constraints constraints4 = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();
        Data myFeedbackMessage = new Data.Builder()
                .putString("myFeedbackMessageId", message.getId())
                .putString("myFeedbackMessage", message.getFeedbackMessage())
                .putString("myFeedbackPerson", message.getFeedbackPersonName())
                .putString("myFeedbackCreated", message.getCreated().toString())
                .build();

        OneTimeWorkRequest sendFeedbackWorker = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SendFeedbackMessageWorker.class)
                .setInputData(myFeedbackMessage)
                .setConstraints(constraints4)
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(
                sendFeedbackWorker
        );
```

Comment: how much time did you wait after connecting to network to be executed?

Comment: I just tried to wait 15 minutes, doesn't get triggered. The trigger onFailure, and method call to this method. I will get onFailure when I enter flight mode in emulator, disable flight mode and wait 15 minutes... nothing happens. Any suggestion?

Comment: "The trigger onFailure", what I mean is that in my onFailure I will call the method handleFeedbackMessageFailure that I posted in my question.

Comment: `CONNECTED` constraint is a bit misleading because it's actually means "Connected and verified". You can be connected to WiFi but without being connected to the internet - was this the case?

Comment: This was on the Emulator, I pressed "Airplane mode", triggered the API call which then goes to onFailure. Then waited a few moments and un-ticked the "Airplane mode". So I am not sure.
When I tested on my real device it actually somehow worked... thing is, on the real device I don't have any Cellular, so I un-ticked "WiFi", then triggered API call->onFailure, and then ticked "WiFi". The worker ran, but I cannot run debug with breakpoints from IDE to phone, still could see in logs and DB that message was sent... beats me

Comment: So maybe it is a problem with this CONNECTED constraint... what else could I use? The reason we have this method call to re-send when onFailure method is reached is that we suspect users will lose their WiFi connection from time to time. And with connection, I mean they will most likely not un-tick WiFi but rather go out of range from AP/Router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the JS info as described here:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging

Use:
adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler

In the result - check what is unstatisfied in the Constraints section.

If it is Connectivity:

Check what Capabilities you expect(part of the logs in the job info) and compare them to the current active network Capabilities.

Also if not enough time is the problem - you will see it there in the constraints.

Comment: I used this and compared when I changed code. Actually we had a problem with our background workers not fetching the oauth tokens correct, but this helped a lot steering us to right direction. Thanks

Comment: @CompileNow great! :) Good luck! :)